# Undefined symbol errors after updating the fbsdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdkloginkit

I have implemented facebook login in the application, which started giving me error because of old fbsdk version so i updated pod file using `pod install` command and after that i got library not found ~IBolt. Once i removed the IBolt from linking i am getting 30+ Undefined symbol errors i.e

`Undefined symbol: vtable for __cxxabiv1::__pointer_type_info`

`Undefined symbol: vtable for __cxxabiv1::__function_type_info`

What i have tried

Deintegrate pod using `pod deintegrate`
i cleaned derived data folder
After all this i am still getting the undefied symbol erros.

Comment: Facebook SDKs have to changing many times over the years. So you need to check all the versions at your various steps. e.g., what version of the facebook related pods were you using? what is the version of the "old fbsdk version"?